# PCA colour grouping dependent on the column names

Tags: r, pca

I wated to do a PCA analysis and visualisation, it seem easy but I can't figure out how get the different groups in different colouring.
My data look like this :

```
  V1   meanLL   meanML     meanHL   meanFL
 1 AT3G02730 22684834 24936025 22896942.1 26281180
 2 AT5G51570      NaN  2946262  4513876.3      NaN
 3 AT2G41680  7080077  2461699  1697517.9  5756359
 4 AT5G19855      NaN  2655188        NaN  2242139
 5 ATCG00190  1669609  1783529   721131.7  1943212
 6 AT2G36885  2729459  5683605  7895497.2  6903475
 >
```

I have found some useful packages for it

```
library(ggfortify)
library(ggplot2)
y <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                text = " V1   meanLL   meanML     meanHL   meanFL
                1 AT3G02730 22684834 24936025 22896942.1 26281180
                2 AT5G51570      NaN  2946262  4513876.3      NaN
                3 AT2G41680  7080077  2461699  1697517.9  5756359
                4 AT5G19855      NaN  2655188        NaN  2242139
                5 ATCG00190  1669609  1783529   721131.7  1943212
                6 AT2G36885  2729459  5683605  7895497.2  6903475")

df <-log(y[, c(2,3,4,5)])
df<- na.omit(df)
autoplot(prcomp(df))
```

so the most basic plot I can get with that but when it comes to colours i am lost, because my groups are my names of the columns...

```
 autoplot(prcomp(df), data = y, colour = colnames(y)

 autoplot(prcomp(df), data = y , loadings = TRUE)
```

I want colours, my boss want colours, help, please help

Comment: Have a look at the package `factoextra`and its function `fviz()`. There are also some good tutorials available, e.g., here [link](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/112-pca-principal-component-analysis-essentials/) (PCA essentials at stdha).

Comment: what about the columns? you will have nrow points so you need nrow colors, not 4--that's what the commenter in your previous question was getting at. for example, you could color by which column with the max value per row `df$col <- factor(colnames(df)[apply(df, 1L, which.max)]); autoplot(prcomp(df[, 1:4]), df, colour = 'col')`

Comment: I figured out that when I transpose it it will be easier final_y <- as.data.frame(t(y))  but than i get problem with calsses, this is night mare

Comment: `final_y <- as.data.frame(t(y[, -1]))`

Comment: library(reshape2)
yy<-dcast(melt(y), variable~V1)  finally I did it like this